# PropertyInfo.SetValue Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, reflection

I've a similar error to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755646/setvalue-on-propertyinfo-instance-error-object-does-not-match-target-type-c-sh), but unfortunately not the same simple solution.  Here is the code:

```
public virtual void MapObject(T obj, IViewModel<T> viewModel, ITPSDataAccess dataAccess)
{
    var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    var dtoProps = viewModel.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var dtoProp in dtoProps)
    {
        var objProp = dtoProps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == dtoProp.Name);
        if (objProp != null)
        {
            var dtoVal = dtoProp.GetValue(viewModel, null);
            objProp.SetValue(obj, dtoVal, null); // ERROR HERE
        }
    }
     ...
}
```

The error occurs at the point indicated, stating "Object does not match target type".  It looks like I'm passing the correct object to be set - I am therefore unable to solve the problem.

I've also tried to take the advice of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443274/cannot-get-propertyinfo-setvalue-to-set-the-value-on-my-object), and examine the types of property I'm attempting to set which throw the exception - the property in question is a string, and the setter does not appear to be broken since it works under normal, non-reflection circumstances.

Comment: Add `objProp.PropertyType` and `dtoVal.GetType()` to the Watch debugger window, and set a breakpoint on the call to `objProp.SetValue(...)`. When the breakpoint is hit, what do those two expressions evaluate to? They need to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake seems to be here:

```
var objProp = dtoProps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == dtoProp.Name);
```

I think you meant:

```
var objProp = objProps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == dtoProp.Name);
```

Comment: THanks, man - that was one of those ones you stare at for 30mins and it takes 3s for someone else to see it... !