# Object does not match target type PropertyInfo SetValue - one class to another

Tags: c#, reflection, types, propertyinfo, setvalue

So I have 2 classes, both have identical Property names. One class contains different variables: `int`, `strings`, `bool` and `DateTime` The second class contains only 1 `int` and the rest are all strings.

Now I want to loop through all the properties, get the value from class1, encrypt that data and save it as a string in obj2, then return it to the main form (to save it in a database later).

```
public PersoonEncrypted EncryptPersonClass(Class1 object1)
    {
        PersoonEncrypted persEncrypt = new PersoonEncrypted(); //second class obj

        Type type = object1.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        Type type2 = persEncrypt.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties2 = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var bothProperties in properties.Zip(properties2, (obj1, obj2) => new { Obj1 = obj1, Obj2 = obj2 }))
        {
            string value = "";

            value = bothProperties.Obj1.GetValue(object1) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                string encryptValue = Encrypt(value);
                if ((bothProperties.Obj2 != null) && (bothProperties.Obj2.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
                { //!= null check has no effect at all
                    bothProperties.Obj2.SetValue(persEncrypt, encryptValue, null); //errorLine
                }
            }

        }

        return persEncrypt;
    }
```

That is what I came up with until now.
I have, of course, searched for other solutions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059172/propertyinfo-setvalue-object-does-not-match-target-type). This, after applying some own changes, didn't return any errors, but it didn't save any encrypted strings into the class `persEncrypt`. What I concluded was, from that test, is that it was testing if the value in the second class(`persEncrypt` in my example) from the particular property was null, while it shouldn't do that, it should make a new instance of that variable and save it in the object class, but removing that check gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

- you're just `.Zip`-ing the two lists of PropertyInfo objects, which simply iterates through both lists and doesn't check or sort for any sort of matching. This could result in erroneous behavior depending on the order in which properties appear - consider using a [`.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead to match property names.
- This code doesn't check for an indexer on the property before attempting to assign to it without one - any indexed property which is of type `string` will make it to this point and then throw an exception when you try to set it.
- Because this code is calling into [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), there's the possibility an exception is being thrown by the code of the Property itself. This is where a StackTrace from your exception could reveal much more about what's happening.
- Your code also checks for a property of type `string` directly - when using reflection you should use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead in order to allow for inherited types, though that is unlikely the issue in this one case.

Comment: i'll check the join method tomorrow, looks like a good solution, if it works than I'll provide the answer unless someone else is quick enough in the meantime.